# Problem with NetLogo monitor reporter won't show right value

Tags: netlogo

So I want to program a monitor to go up by +1 if any patch turns blue

The reporter for my monitor is:

`ifelse-value any? patches[
[bank] of patches]
[0]
the code is:
to count-bewohnbar
  ask patches[
    if bewohnbar? = true [set Bank Bank + 1]
    ]`

but all the monitor shows is [000233900000...]
so it just shows random strings of numbers.
Another problem that I tackled in another question of mine, was,
I have another monitor with the money variable, it works and I want to create a link between the two in this way:

```
ask patches[
    let Bank count (patches with [pcolor = blue])
     if-else (pcolor = blue) [
     if (Bank + 1)  [set money money - 100]
      ]
    [ if Bank Bank - 1 [set money money + 50]
     ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 2):

When `of` is applied to an agentset, e.g., `patches`, it will give you a list of the value of the variable or reporter in the brackets for each agent in the set. Since the agents are queried randomly, the list will be in random order.  Thus

```
ifelse-value any? patches[
[bank] of patches]
[0]
```

will give you the a list of the value of `bank` reported by each patch, in random order.  (Since there are always patches, `any? patches` will always be true, so what you have written is the same as

```
[bank] of patches]
```

). Since the list you show has different values for different patches, I assume that `bank` is a `patch-only` variable and not a global value.  (If it were the latter, the list would have the same value for every patch.)

The question, then, is what `bank` is supposed to represent.  From the code you supply, it appears that each patch increments its value of `bank` if `bewohnbar?` is true. (By the way, the condition `if bewohnbar? = true [` is the same as simply `if bewohnbar? [`. `if` expects a logical value or expression, and `bewohnbar?` is already a logical.)  Does `bewohnbar?` have something to do with the patch being blue?  If so, `bank` is incremented at each call to `count-bewohnbar` so it positive, but possibly greater than one for any patch that has turned blue, which is why the values in the list you see are different for the different patches.  They represent how many ticks the patch has been blue (if `count-bewohnbar` is called once per tick).

A reporter that counted how many patches there are for which `bewohnbar?` is (or has been) true would then be

```
count filter [v -> v > 0] [bank] of patches
```

`filter` takes the list of `bank` values, keeps only those that are greater than zero, and counts them. But, a much simpler approach is to count the number of patches for which `bewohnbar?` is true.

```
count patches with [bewohnbar?]
```